# Prototype script $$('span[tab_caption="abcde"]')[0].select('span[id*=section.]')[0]

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can anyone please help to explain what does this code do? Specifically what does "id*=section." mean?

```
Prototype script $$('span[tab_caption="abcd"]')[0].select('span[id*=section.]')[0]
```

Comment: where is the `id*=section.` piece of the question/code?

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the '.' might be a typo but i'm not sure.  What this appears to be doing is find the first span with attribute `tab_caption=abcd` then within that element, find the first span with id of `*section*`.

When I try this with the trailing '.', I get an error from prototype saying `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id*=section.]"`.  But without the '.' things work out.

Looking at a sample piece of DOM like this

```
 <span tab_caption="ac">
   span ac
   <span id="section1">section1</span>
 </span>
 <span tab_caption="ad">
   span ad
   <span id="section2">section2</span>
 </span>
 <span tab_caption="ac">
   span ac
   <span id="section3">section3</span>
 </span>
 <span tab_caption="ad">
   span ad
   <span id="section4">section4</span>
 </span>
```

Then running those selectors in the console I get:

```
 > $$('span[tab_caption="ac"]')[0].select('span[id*=section]')[0]
 <span id=​"section1">​section1​</span>​
 > $$('span[tab_caption="ad"]')[0].select('span[id*=section]')[0]
 <span id=​"section2">​section2​</span>​
```

As you can see, the first query picked the first span with `tab_caption=ac` and gave me section1.  The second picked the first from `tab_caption=ad` and gave me the first `section*` match which was `section2`.

Are you sure the '.' is supposed to be in the `select` argument?

Comment: Based on the answer above from @knittl, it's possible that though the selector would be valid with CSS3, Prototype doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any to output the selected HTMLs somewhere? for e.g. can I output $$('span[tab_caption="ac"]')[0] somewhere using any tool? potentially firebug?

Comment: Sure.  You don't need Firebug. Just open your javascript console in whatever browser (Chrome -> View -> Developer -> Javascript Console, or Firefox -> Web Console (i think)), load the page, and paste that piece of code in the console.  That's how I was able to see that Prototype didn't like the trailing . and that the selector worked.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute selector was added with CSS3 and matches any [attribute which contains the specified substring](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#attribute-substrings). In your case, any span element which has an id attribute with the string `section.` somewhere in it.

Comment: A [period is allowed as an id value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).